# Not being able to get column values from sql in R shiny for particular date

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, dbi, control-charts

I am newbie in R
I am trying to plot control chart in Shiny using sql database I created.
In below code I am able to get the sql data as per date.
but I am not being able to access the column values for which I have to plot the graph.
Following is the 1st few lines of database:

```
id   product_name    product_config  detected_width  created  
1    Belt            width           69.84           2020-04-19  
2    Belt            width           71.12           2020-04-19
```

In the plot tab, 
I am getting the following error:
Error: 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
So, the column values are not getting selected I guess. Can anyone please help with this.

```
library(pool)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(plotly)
library(qcc)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           h3("Selecting Data"),
           dateInput("date", "Enter a date:", value = Sys.Date())
    ),
    column(8,
           h3("Plot"),
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("tbl")), 
             tabPanel("Control Chart",plotOutput("plot"))
    )
  )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    conn <- dbConnect(
      drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
      dbname = "testdatabase",
      host = "localhost",
      username = "root",
      password = "root"
    )
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
    sql <- "SELECT * FROM Ceat_table WHERE created = ?date1;"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, date1 = input$date)
    dbGetQuery(conn, query)
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    conn <- dbConnect(
      drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
      dbname = "testdatabase",
      host = "localhost",
      username = "root",
      password = "root"
    )
    on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
    sql <- "SELECT * FROM Ceat_table WHERE created = ?date1;"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, date1 = input$date)
    dbGetQuery(conn, query)
    ceatdb <- tbl(conn, "Ceat_table")
    a<-qcc(ceatdb$detected_width,type = "xbar.one")
    plot(a)
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in your `renderPlot` function.

Note that the last command in your `renderTable` function is `dbGetQuery(conn, query)`. This fetches the data from the database, and because it is the last command the results from this command are what are passed to the UI.

In contrast for the `renderPlot` function you access the same table two different ways:

1. Directly as `dbGetQuery(conn, query)` but without storing the fetched results locally.
2. As a remote table with `ceatdb <- tbl(conn, "Ceat_table")` but without loading the results fully into R using `collect()`.

I recommend you only use one of these approaches.

#### Option 1: save the results of `dbGetQuery`:

```r
conn <- dbConnect( your_connection_details_here )
on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)
sql <- "SELECT * FROM Ceat_table WHERE created = ?date1;"
query <- sqlInterpolate(conn, sql, date1 = input$date)

ceatdb = dbGetQuery(conn, query) # key change

a<-qcc(ceatdb$detected_width,type = "xbar.one")
plot(a)
```

#### Option 2: load remote table into memory with `collect()`:

```r
conn <- dbConnect( your_connection_details_here )
on.exit(dbDisconnect(conn), add = TRUE)

ceatdb <- tbl(conn, "Ceat_table") %>% collect() # key change

a<-qcc(ceatdb$detected_width,type = "xbar.one")
plot(a)
```

Note that for remote tables, the `$` notation can not be used to access columns in the same way as for local tables. One way to demonstrate this is to compare the output of `names(my_table)` and `colnames(my_table)`. Local tables will give the same results for both these commands, but remote tables will not.

Comment: I have tried the 2nd approach. and it worked. thanks.